# How to terminate ASIHTTP connection in iphone?

Tags: iphone, authentication, connection, asihttprequest, terminate

I am having an issue with `ASIHTTPRequest` authentication. The steps are in the following order,

1. User entering wrong username and password -- > No data comes from backend and request failed delegate gets called from `ASIHTTPRequest`. Then goto login page again.
2. User enters correct values -- > Data comes as expected and request finished method gets
   called. Then goto login page again.
3. User entering wrong username and password -- > Data again comes and request finished method gets called.

The code which I am using is:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:60];

[request setUsername:User_Name];
[request setPassword:Pass_Word];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setShouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge:NO];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

The backend is handling stateless webservices. What is teh problem ? and what am i doing wrong ? please help me out.

Thanks,
Vinod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe try:

```
[request setUseSessionPersistence:NO];
```

Comment: @user317894 Glad to hear it - assuming it was my answer that solved it, please mark the answer as accepted (click the outline of the tick next to it) and upvote it (the upwards pointing arrow) - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with `shouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallange:YES` (which is the default).

Comment: No Luck man ... Also tried setting shouldattemptpersistentconnection to NO it is also not working :(